ListBoxes on Outlook form are not editable
I am creating an outlook form. I have ComboBoxes and ListBoxes.
The ComboBoxes are working fine. But the ListBoxes are not editable. I can't place the cursor into the box.
Properties are ser as follows:
Visible
Enabled
Sunken
Advanced Properties are set as follows
Properties
Advanced Properties
As recently as two weeks prior, I was able to create editable Lisboxes.
I would appreciate any thoughts on why my ListBoxes are not editable.
